# RedisTokenstore: Cannot cast ...User to ...User

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I switched my Spring OAuth2 app to the RedisTokenstore. Now on accessing the principal, basically through ...

`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication.userAuthentication.principal as User`

... I get a ...

`java.lang.ClassCastException: ...User cannot be cast to ...User`

(three dots are in reality the full class path).

I'm quite new to jave / kotlin and do only have a vague understanding of what is going on.

A few hints:

- I'm quite sure that the redis token store does not store in the meantime, so the content should be the same (`storeAccessToken` is not called in the request in question)
- I see that `readAccessToken` is called twice (which i think is an unneeded roundtrip, but that's a different thing)
- The mixup happens within the `doFilter` method of a Security Chain Method, namely on the second walk through.

*Update*: The serial version hickhup was because I did not flush redis cache after adding the serial. So it's just the `cannot cast` error.

How can I start debugging this?

Comment: I understand you're trying to make it easier for us to understand, but you shouldn't replace the classpath with `...` as it makes it harder for us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually an issue in spring-devtools:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools-known-restart-limitations

> **20.2.7 Known Limitations**
>
> Restart functionality does not work well with objects that are deserialized by using a standard ObjectInputStream.
>   If you need to deserialize data, you may need to use Spring’s
>   ConfigurableObjectInputStream in combination with
>   Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().
>
> Unfortunately, several third-party libraries deserialize without
>   considering the context classloader. If you find such a problem, you
>   need to request a fix with the original authors.

One option is to upgrade to spring-boot 2.+

Another is to remove devtools alltogether assuming you don't need it. Here is an example if you are using Maven that would remove any version from 1.3.0 and above:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <version>[1.3.0,)</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Be sure to first flush Redis once complete to verify.

Comment: I use latest spring boot. Removing the devtools did not help.

Comment: Removing dev tools did indeed work. I just needed to flush redis. Thanks.

Comment: @shredding I'll update the answer to include flushing redis. Glad it worked out for you.